# LWC for show-address-lookup address

Tags: lightning-web-components

```html
 <div class="slds-card slds-theme_default slds-p-left_x-large" style="border-radius: 5px;">
        <h2 class="slds-card__header-title slds-m-top_medium slds-text-title_bold">
            <strong class="slds-text-heading_large">Account Address</strong>
            <span class="slds-text-body_regular slds-p-top_x-small">
                (
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick={openEditAddressModal} class="slds-link">Change Address</a>
                )
            </span>
        </h2>
        <p>
            {mailingStreet}<br>
            {mailingCity} {mailingState} {mailingPostalCode}<br>
            {mailingCountry}<br>
        </p>
        
    </div>

    <template if:true={isEditModalOpen}>
        <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">New Address</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning-card title="Address Lookup using Google Maps Places API">
                        <lightning-input-address
                            address-label="Shipping Address"
                            street-label="Street"
                            city-label="City"
                            country-label="Country"
                            province-label="Province"
                            postal-code-label="PostalCode"
                            street="Default Street Line"
                            city=""
                            country=""
                            province=""
                            postal-code=""
                            required
                            field-level-help="Select Shipping Address"
                            show-address-lookup="true">
                        </lightning-input-address>
                    </lightning-card>
                    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={saveAddress} class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick={cancelEdit}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template if:true={isEditModalOpen}>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
```

JS

```js
    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import { getFieldValue, getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    
    export default class accRenewalTest_AccountBillingAddress extends LightningElement {
        @api contactId ='0038C00000QyuzsQAB';
        @api recordId;
        @track isEditModalOpen = false;
        @track editedStreet = '';
        @track editedCity = '';
        @track editedState = '';
        @track editedPostalcode = '';
        @track editedCountry = '';
      //  @track totalAmount = 0;

    contactFields = [
        'Contact.MailingStreet',
        'Contact.MailingCity',
        'Contact.MailingState',
        'Contact.MailingPostalCode',
        'Contact.MailingCountry'
    ];

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$contactId', fields: '$contactFields' })
    contact;

    get mailingStreet() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, 'Contact.MailingStreet');
    }

    get mailingCity() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, 'Contact.MailingCity');
    }

    get mailingState() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, 'Contact.MailingState');
    }

    get mailingPostalCode() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, 'Contact.MailingPostalCode');
    }

    get mailingCountry() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, 'Contact.MailingCountry');
    }

    openEditAddressModal() {
        this.isEditModalOpen = true;
        this.editedStreet = this.mailingStreet;
        this.editedCity = this.mailingCity;
        this.editedState = this.mailingState;
        this.editedPostalcode = this.mailingPostalCode;
        this.editedCountry = this.mailingCountry;
    }

    handleStreetChange(event) {
        this.editedStreet = event.target.value;
    }

    handleCityChange(event) {
        this.editedCity = event.target.value;
    }

    handleStateChange(event) {
        this.editedState = event.target.value;
    }

    handlePostalcodeChange(event) {
        this.editedPostalcode = event.target.value;
    }

    handleCountryChange(event) {
        this.editedCountry = event.target.value;
    }

  

     /* handleCheckboxChange(event) {
            const checkbox = event.target;
            const isChecked = checkbox.checked;
            const duesAmount = parseFloat(checkbox.dataset.amount || '0');
            this.totalAmount += isChecked ? duesAmount : -duesAmount;
        }*/

    saveAddress() {
    const addressLookup = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
    if (addressLookup) {
        const address = addressLookup.value;
        const fields = {};
        fields['Contact.MailingStreet'] = this.editedStreet;
        fields['Contact.MailingCity'] = this.editedCity;
        fields['Contact.MailingState'] = this.editedState;
        fields['Contact.MailingPostalCode'] = this.editedPostalcode;
        fields['Contact.MailingCountry'] = this.editedCountry;

        console.log('Fields to be updated:', fields);
    }
        updateRecord({
            fields,
            recordId: this.recordId
        })
            .then(() => {
                this.isEditModalOpen = false;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Address updated successfully',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error updating record: ', error);
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: 'Error updating address: ' + error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
        cancelEdit() {
            this.isEditModalOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

After clicking the "Save" button, I am unable to save the address, and on the user interface (UI) as well, the address is not getting updated.

Comment: "unable to save the address": please be more specific. What exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code like below and it is working fine.
I have added the js variable into the HTML in lightning-input-address and also added the change handler method to get the changed value of the address.

Also, make some changes to the js file as listed below.

- Imported all contact fields and passed them into the wire.
- Added the handleChangeAddress method to get the updated address.
- UpdateRecord method added into the if condition.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-button variant="base" label="Open Modal" title="titleName" onclick={onBtnclick}></lightning-button>
    <template if:true={isEditModalOpen}>
        <div class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">New Address</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                    <lightning-card title="Address Lookup using Google Maps Places API">
                        <lightning-input-address name="Address" address-label="Shipping Address" street-label="Street"
                            city-label="City" country-label="Country" province-label="Province"
                            postal-code-label="PostalCode" street={editedStreet} city={editedCity} country={editedCountry} province={editedState}
                            postal-code={editedPostalcode} required field-level-help="Select Shipping Address" onchange={handleChangeAddress} 
                            show-address-lookup="true">
                        </lightning-input-address>
                    </lightning-card>
                    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={saveAddress}
                            class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
                        <lightning-button label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick={cancelEdit}></lightning-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <template if:true={isEditModalOpen}>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getFieldValue, getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import STREET_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingStreet";
import CITY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingCity";
import STATE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingState";
import POSTALCODE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingPostalCode";
import COUNTRY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Contact.MailingCountry";

export default class Test_AccountBillingAddress extends LightningElement {
    //@api contactId = '0032t00000RArlQAAT';
    @api recordId;
    @track isEditModalOpen = false;
    @track editedStreet = '';
    @track editedCity = '';
    @track editedState = '';
    @track editedPostalcode = '';
    @track editedCountry = '';
    //  @track totalAmount = 0;

   
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [STREET_FIELD, CITY_FIELD, STATE_FIELD, POSTALCODE_FIELD, COUNTRY_FIELD]})
    contact;

    get mailingStreet() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, STREET_FIELD);
    }

    get mailingCity() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CITY_FIELD);
    }

    get mailingState() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, STATE_FIELD);
    }

    get mailingPostalCode() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, POSTALCODE_FIELD);
    }

    get mailingCountry() {
        return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, COUNTRY_FIELD);
    }

    onBtnclick() {
        this.openEditAddressModal();
    }

    openEditAddressModal() {
        this.isEditModalOpen = true;
        this.editedStreet = this.mailingStreet;
        this.editedCity = this.mailingCity;
        this.editedState = this.mailingState;
        this.editedPostalcode = this.mailingPostalCode;
        this.editedCountry = this.mailingCountry;
    }
    
    handleChangeAddress(event){
        if(event.target.name == "Address"){
            this.editedStreet = event.target.street;
            this.editedCity = event.target.city;
            this.editedState = event.target.country;
            this.editedPostalcode = event.target.province;
            this.editedCountry = event.target.postalCode;
        }
    }

    saveAddress() {
        const addressLookup = this.template.querySelector('lightning-input-address');
        if (addressLookup) {
            const address = addressLookup.value;
            var fields = {
                Id: this.recordId,
                MailingStreet : this.editedStreet,
                MailingCity : this.editedCity,
                MailingState : this.editedState,
                MailingPostalCode : this.editedPostalcode,
                MailingCountry : this.editedCountry
            };
            const recordInput = { fields };
            console.log('Fields to be updated:', JSON.stringify(fields));
            updateRecord(recordInput)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Success: ');
                    this.isEditModalOpen = false;
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Address updated successfully',
                            variant: 'success'
                        })
                    );
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error updating record: ', error);
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Error',
                            message: 'Error updating address: ' + error.body.message,
                            variant: 'error'
                        })
                    );
                });
        }

    }
    cancelEdit() {
        this.isEditModalOpen = false;
    }
}
```